# lftp with key + passphrase

Tags: linux, key, sftp, passphrase, lftp

I'm using **lftp** to send files to an SFTP server, but I don't how to connect with key and passphrase.

So in `sftp`, I can do this:

```
sftp -i .ssh/id_rsa.mykey login@my.host.fr
Enter passphrase for key '.ssh/id_rsa.mykey': my passphrase here
```

So, how can I use lftp with this connection method?

I have also tried:

```
lftp -e "set ssl:key-file .ssh/id_rsa.mykey" sftp://my.host.fr
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must specify the username, and just pass anything as the password, to skip it asking.

```
lftp -u user,xxx sftp://...
```

Comment: `lftp -u user, sftp://hostname` also works (note the comma)

Comment: For some reason, this does not work if you need to send a private key AND a password. The password is not sent, or it is not sent correctly.

Answer (score 24):

An answer based off [Jean-Luc Boss's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577090/lftp-with-key-passphrase/17783480#17783480) and wiak's, but a bit more explicit:

To connect to a server, `lftp` uses an `ssh` command, by default `ssh -a -x`. It doesn't have an explicit option for changing the keyfile to use, but as you note, `ssh` does, so we just need to set `lftp` to connect using `ssh -a -x -i <keyfile>` before it connects.

You can do this in a few ways:

- If you're using lftp's interactive command line, run the following command before you connect:

  ```
  set sftp:connect-program "ssh -a -x -i <keyfile>"
  ```
- If you're specifying a bunch of commands to `lftp` using `-c`, just add that set command to the start of your command sequence:

  ```
  lftp -c 'set sftp:connect-program "ssh -a -x -i <keyfile>"; connect sftp://user@example.com; mirror -eR files; ...'
  ```
- If you always going to want to use the same key, just add that `set ...` line from the first bullet to your `~/.lftprc` file (or one of the other configuration file options listed in `man lftp`).

Comment: You must have a user that can connect throught SSH.

Answer (score 8):

Just add:

```
set sftp:connect-program "ssh -a -x -i yourprivatekeyfile"
```

to your `~/.lftprc`, as most of the settings can be set permanently there.

Answer (score 2):

LFTP doesn't seem to pass or does not use the identity file specified with "ssl:key-file" with SSH. You have to specify it in the sftp:connect-program option:

```
ssh -a -x -i yourprivatekeyfile
```

This should work.