# Upload file from local to sftp based remote server using shell/bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sftp, file-transfer

I'm looking for a shell/bash script that can be used to transfer a file from my local to a remote serve using sftp protocol.

I have the one for ftp but can't figure out for sftp.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lftp`:

```
lftp -u USER,PASS -e "put LOCAL_FILE;quit" sftp://SERVER_ADDRESS
```

Comment: Does the server_address here means server address/remote_path or how do i include the remote path. Also if i wanted to use ssh key here how would i use that instead of password.

Comment: You can add /path in the SERVER_ADDRESS. About the key, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577090/lftp-with-key-passphrase